# XPath to identify a parent based on two related children

Tags: xpath

Using the following Example, I am trying to create an XPath that will identify the id of Apples where their branchID matches the ID of a branch, but the treeID doesn't match the branch's treeID.

for instance: //growth[@type="apple"][branchID=//branch/@id]/@id   - results would be 
Granny
Empire
Gala

And //growth[@type="apple"][treeID!=//branch/treeID]/@id - results would be
Granny
Empire
Gala

But I want a query that will only return:
Granny

```
<xml>
  <growth type="apple" id="Granny">
   <branchID>ABCD</branchID>
   <treeID>456</treeID>
  </growth>
  <growth type="apple" id="Empire">
   <branchID>ABCD</branchID>
   <treeID>123</treeID>
  </growth>
  <growth type="apple" id="Gala">
   <branchID>EFGH</branchID>
   <treeID>456</treeID>
  </growth>
  <growth type="flower" id="white">
   <branchID>EFGH</branchID>
   <treeID>123</treeID>
  </growth>
  <growth type="flower" id="yellow">
   <branchID>ABCD</branchID>
   <treeID>456</treeID>
  </growth>
  <branch id="ABCD">
   <treeID>123</treeID>
  </branch>
  <branch id="EFGH">
    <treeID>456</treeID>
  </branch>
  <tree id="123" />
  <tree id="456" />
  <tree id="789" />
 </xml>
```

Comment: Why the query should only return `Granny`?

Answer (score 1):

So the required item(s) (where the branchID/treeID pair does not exist in a branch element) will have different index values for the branchID in the list of all //branch/@id values and the treeID in the list of all //branch/treeID values...

```
//growth[@type="apple"][index-of(//branch/@id,branchID)!=index-of(//branch/treeID,treeID)]/@id

Granny
```

Nice question to give the little grey cells some exercise on a Friday lunchtime :o)

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion - it did work on the Apples example but didn't work on my actual XML... however, you got me going in the right direction and I wouldn't have figured it out without your help - so thanks again! 
What I ended up doing:
//growth[@type="apple"][not(index-of(//branch/@id,branchID)=index-of(//branch/treeID,treeID))]/@id

Just a simple change from "!=" to "not( = )" did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: OK, so the query worked in an XML editor... but not in SQL. Got the following error:
XQuery [@ApplesQuery.blob.exist()]: There is no function '{http://www.w3.org/2004/07/xpath-functions}:index-of()'

Thoughts???

Comment: Is your database SQL Server by any chance?  Unfortunately that seems to have a somewhat restricted implementation of XPath 2.0 (see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189254.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx#sql2k5_xqueryintro_topic11)) and I haven't come up with another way to do it I'm afraid.